# Writing text file in thread

Tags: c#, file-io

```
if (f3.Length > 0)
{
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(path3, File.Exists(path3) ? FileMode.Truncate : FileMode.Create
        , FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.Write(f3);
    }
}
```

This code is in one thread which is called every x seconds. I write to the file first time, and I can write to it after that, although I do not get an exception.

Comment: is there a question hidden in there somewhere?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I think this is more a celebration of being an answer. See, every time he writes the file it doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: So... is there some kind of problem you want help with, or did you just want to let us know you could write a file multiple times without generating an exception?

Comment: Question is why can't I write new file after first write.

Comment: So do you, or don't you get an exception the second time you write to the file? You might want to edit your question.

Comment: @elninho edit your Original question and add this comment to post.

Answer (score 4):

> Question is why can't I write new file after first write.

Because your code specifically tells it how to.  `File.Exists(path3) ? FileMode.Truncate : FileMode.Create`  This specifically is creating a stream that creates a new file if none is there, and truncates the file if one *is* there (rather than just erroring out).

Comment: I thought Why can't I replace the text.

Comment: You can.  You should edit your question to specify, in detail, both what your code is currently doing and what you would like to to do, if this answer isn't sufficient for you.